# multithread handling in AM1808 using embedded Linux

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, arm, sqlite, multithreading

I am using AM1808 ARM9 based board using GCC compiler (UBUNTU 10.04) .
I am using Sqlite3 database management.
I have some requirement regarding handling threads in background having access on database more then 3 or 4 times simultaneously.

I found that I need to Cross compile the Sqlite3 with the Multithreading option(THREADSAFE = 1) enabled.

I am not getting that How i can Cross Compile the Sqlite3.7.15 with the Serialized or Mutithread option enabled ?

I stuck here and due to this i am getting uncertain errors. and my system gets stuck on Thread.

I have already cross compiled my sqlite3.7.15 using following command.

> sudo ./configure
>   --exec-prefix=/media/8CCC8E9BCC8E7F68/SQLIte3/sqliteinstall/  --host=arm --target=arm CC=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
>   AR=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
>   STRIP=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
>   RANLIB=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="-Os"

Comment: I got the solution.I have used thread synchronization techniques for that. I have used mutexes for locking the database. I make sure that my database should be modified by a single thread only at a time by using mutexes.and it works. thank you. Please go through the following link http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html for the cross compilation specifications. Thank You.